# How to close a browser tab from its origin

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm able to open a new tab and then close it from its parent doing something like this:

```
<a id="mylink" href="javascript:" onclick="mynewwindow = window.open('https://www.google.co.in');" target="_blank">Sample Code</a>
    <a href="javascript:" onclick="closemywindow();">close</a>
    <script>
        var mynewwindow;
        function closemywindow(){
            mynewwindow.close();
        }
</script>
```

But if the new tab is opened through the context menu or using the scroll, how could I close that new tab?

Answer (score 0):

The result of window.open is just another reference to a window. In your page you can just use window.close.

Just be aware that if it is the only open tab it might ask the user to permit closing the window.

Thanks to Darren's comment I understand that you might want to close windows from a central point. That could work with an external web service. Your links could be in the form http://anotherpage?openedfrom=thispage and then the new page might connect periodically to a central point and see if it needs to close. From the original page you might instruct the service to "close all windows opened by this". In this context, 'thispage' would be a randomly generated key to identify the opening page.

If you only want to do it on the current browser, you might even not need to use a web service and instead use [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Here is some code for it (the test html file was called test13.html - change the name appropriately):

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<a href="test13.html" target="_blank">A link</a><br/>
<input type="button" value="Close all opened windows"/>
<script>
function guid() { //generates a random GUID like string
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
}

window.windowKey=guid(); //generates a key for the window
//uncomment this if you want all the opened pages to share a key
//var m=/[\?&]windowKey=([^\?&]+)/.exec(document.location.href);
//if (m) window.windowKey=m[1];


if (!window.localStorage) {
    alert('No local storage, no autoclosing pages');
} else {
    $('input').click(function() { //click on the button to close all pages referred by this one
        window.localStorage.setItem(windowKey,"yes");
    });

    window.localStorage.setItem(windowKey,"no"); // you could skip this if you don't want to list the opened window keys
    $(window).on('beforeunload',function() {
        window.localStorage.removeItem(windowKey); // clean up localStorage
    });


    setInterval(function() {
        var m=/[\?&]windowKey=([^\?&]+)/.exec(document.location.href);
        if (!m) return;
        var referralKey=m[1]; //get the key from the windowKey URL parameter
        var shouldClose=window.localStorage.getItem(referralKey)=="yes";
        if (shouldClose) window.close(); //close this page if the key is marked for closing
    },1000);


    // you might want to execute this on window.ready
    $('a').each(function() { //add the window key to all the links on the page
        var a=$(this);
        var url=a.attr('href');
        url=url+(/\?/.test(url)?'&':'?')+'windowKey='+windowKey;
        a.attr('href',url);
    });
}
</script>
```

If you want to support the scenario: page A opens page B that opens page C and then A closes B and C, change the guid line like this:

```
window.windowKey=guid();
var m=/[\?&]windowKey=([^\?&]+)/.exec(document.location.href);
if (m) window.windowKey=m[1];
```

Comment: This doesn't work - he wants to know how to close the tab FROM the page that he opened it from (such as right-click and open in new tab) (believe that's what he's hoping for..

Comment: I added some code to solve the problem in the question, but I don't believe it is a good design. Doable, though, provided you don't open links with another instance of a browser.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be that on all your pages there's a script that has a timer which closes the window unless there's a mouse event on the page.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   var timeoutID;
   timeoutID = window.setTimeout(closeWindow, 2000);
   document.addEventListener('mousemove', clearAlert, false);

   function clearAlert() {
      window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', clearAlert, false);
   }
   function closeWindow() {
      window.close();
   }
});
```

I'm not entirely sure if it would work or not but it might also always close the window on a mobile or the browser won't execute the script until you switch to the tab

Answer (score -1):

You cannot close windows that were *not* created with window.open(). This would be a really bad behavior, e.g. because in doing so the tab history would also be removed. The tab belongs to the user, not you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close